# How to get a right vertical alignment in lstlisting

Tags: listings

I am writing some SQL code in LaTeX, but the rendering is not that satisfying. I'll leave the code I wrote down

```
\begin{lstlisting}
create table Dipartimento
(
    Codice          char(3) primary key,
    Nome            varchar(50)
);

create table Impiegato
(
    Matricola       char(4) primary key,
    Nome            varchar(30),
    Cognome         varchar(30),
    CodDip          char(3) 
                    references Dipartimento (Codice)
                    on update cascade
                    on delete set null
)
\end{lstlisting}
```

which is rendered in:

[image]

The options I'm actually using for listing package are the following

```
\lstset{frame=false, %trblr, false, none
language=SQL,
aboveskip=3mm,
belowskip=3mm,
showstringspaces=false,
columns=flexible,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
numbers=left, %=left (numera le righe di codice)
numberstyle=\color{gray}, %\tiny per diminuire dimensione
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
%commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
%stringstyle=\color{mauve},
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
tabsize=4,
captionpos=b,
backgroundcolor=\color{black!10},
morekeywords={references},
showstringspaces=false,
tab=$\bullet$\space,
showtabs=true,
%stringstyle=\rmfamily,
% vocali accentate
inputencoding=utf8, 
extendedchars=true,
literate={à}{{\`a}}1 {°}{{\textdegree}}1
}
```

As I show in the following picture (i've set the option showtabs=true) the vertical alignment is kinda wrong, resulting in not aligned words. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance

[image]

**EDIT: Testing code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=false, %trblr, false, none
language=SQL,
aboveskip=3mm,
belowskip=3mm,
showstringspaces=false,
columns=flexible,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
numbers=left, %=left (numera le righe di codice)
numberstyle=\color{gray}, %\tiny per diminuire dimensione
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
%commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
%stringstyle=\color{mauve},
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
tabsize=4,
captionpos=b,
backgroundcolor=\color{black!10},
morekeywords={references},
showstringspaces=false,
tab=$\bullet$\space,
showtabs=true,
%stringstyle=\rmfamily,
% vocali accentate
inputencoding=utf8, 
extendedchars=true,
literate={à}{{\`a}}1 {°}{{\textdegree}}1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
create table Dipartimento
(
Codice          char(3) primary key,
Nome            varchar(50)
);

create table Impiegato
(
Matricola        char(4) primary key,
Nome             varchar(30),
Cognome          varchar(30),
CodDip           char(3) 
                 references Dipartimento (Codice)
                 on update cascade
                 on delete set null
)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

In a blank document, with the same options, i get the result i wish... what's going on?

Comment: your code is not complete and can not be tested, but try to remove columns=flexible.

Comment: oh sorry, i'm editing the post

Comment: you're solution actually works, but (obv) the chars get spaced. Isn't there any other alternative?

Comment: read the documentation about the options regarding spacing and aligment and try out which one is the best for you.

Comment: something like `\lstset{ basicstyle = \ttfamily , columns = fullflexible , keepspaces = true }` should be what you want, I think…

Comment: yes!! That's exaclty what i meant! Thank you @cgnieder! Thank you both guys for your time